# React Redux - sorting array by 2 parameters

Tags: reactjs, sorting

I am using React and redux to build an 'appointment schedule' feature for my app. At this point, I am receiving my array of objects where each object represents an appointment with properties 'date' and 'startTime'. My question is how can I sort my array by both date and time so that sooner appointments come first?

Here is my reducer (upcomingAppointments is the variable where I am storing the array):

```
       case 'SCHEDULE_APT_SUCCESS':
           //console.log('actions payload: ', action.payload )
           return {
                ...state,
                isSchedulingApt: false,
                newlyAddedApt: action.payload,
                aptScheduleDone: true,
                upcomingAppointments: [...state.upcomingAppointments, action.payload]
            };
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Let suppose your array looks something like this:

```
const upcomingAppointments = [
    { date: 'Wed Jun 03 2020', time: '11:39:04' },
    { date: 'Tue Jun 02 2020', time: '16:03:04' },
    { date: 'Wed Jun 03 2020', time: '17:59:12' },
    // ...
];
```

Using [Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), you can provide a custom sort function as argument:

```
const sortedAppointments = upcomingAppointments.sort((a, b) => {
    const dateA = Date.parse(a.date + ' ' + a.time);
    const dateB = Date.parse(b.date + ' ' + b.time);

    // Sort in descending order
    return dateA < dateB ? 1 : -1;
});
```